# Which surahs have been explicitly highlighted as recommended to memorize to obtain knowledge about Allah's rulings?

Tags: fiqh, reference-request, sahaba, surah, quran-memorization

Certainly memorizing the Qur'an is a good deed and highly recommended. I remember having read some statements of the sahaba (in the book hayat as-Sahaba: the life of the companions) saying that one should learn/memorize certain surahs, for example surat an-Nisa' because it covers the topic of heritage and so on.

So which surahs have been recommended to memorize for fiqh (knowledge about the halal and haram and about the rules of Allah) reasons in first place and by whom?

Please consider adding evidences: who said one should learn the surah's x,y,z and where is it covered!